# Is there any way for me to fix this if statement?

Tags: lua

I am relatively new to coding on Lua but I have a little bit of experience in Python. I wanted to try something different where a random number would be rolled and you had to try and guess what the number would be. If you got it right the program would end and that would be it just something simple to work on in my free time. However, I ran into a problem with Lua where this if statement on Line 16 won't work.

```lua
print("Test")
print("--------------------------------------")

game = 1

x = math.random(1,6)

while game == 1 do
  x = math.random(1,6)
  io.write("Enter a number. If you roll that number on the dice you win: ")
  user_input = io.read()
  print(" ")
  print("You chose " .. user_input)
  print(" ")
  print(x)
  if user_input == x then -------------> this line doesn't work
    print(" ")
    print("You rolled the number you chose.")
    game = 2
  else
    print(" ")
    print("You did not roll the random number.")
    print("--------------------------------------")
  end
end
```

Comment: `math.random(1,6)` returns number. `io.read()` returns string.  A number never equals to a string.  Use `tostring()` or `tonumber()` before comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are taking input from the console and storing it as a string. You currently are comparing a string to a integer. Which means that you will always end up in false. Here I changed your code to make it take input as a integer instead of a string so that the statement works now.

```
 print("Test")
 print("--------------------------------------")

 game = 1

 x = math.random(1,6)

 while game == 1 do
   x = math.random(1,6)
   io.write("Enter a number. If you roll that number on the dice you win: ")
   user_input = io.read("*number")
   print(" ")
   print("You chose " .. user_input)
   print(" ")
   print(x)
   if user_input == x then
     print(" ")
     print("You rolled the number you chose.")
     game = 2
   else
     print(" ")
     print("You did not roll the random number.")
     print("--------------------------------------")
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if user_input == x then` with `if tonumber( user_input ) == x then`. It ought to be obvious to you that `user_input` is a string, and `x` is a number; and there is no implicit type cast in Lua.

Bonuses:

- you can drop the parentheses in function calls, if the only parametre is a string or a table: `f("a")` → `f'a'`,
- to end the loop, you can simply use `break`, getting rid of `game` variable altogether (use `while ( true )`),
- always, until you have some special reason not to, declare your variables as `local`. In your example this applies to `x` and `user_input` and would apply to `game`, were it not redundant,
- Lua has HereDoc syntax, so that you can replace:

```lua
    print(" ")
    print("You did not roll the random number.")
    print("--------------------------------------")
```

with

```lua
    print [[

You did not roll the random number.
--------------------------------------
]]
```

Comment: you can also do `print('\nYou did not roll the random number.\n--------------------------------------')` and removing the parentheses should be a crime

Comment: @Nifim, my tired eyes disagree.

Comment: readability is important. `stringplus"potato":mymatch"tato":totable()`

Comment: @Nifim, add spaces before quotes, replace double quotes with single ones and you'll have more readable (for humans) statement than with parentheses.
Although, the decision, when to drop the parentheses should be based on semantic reasons, rather than be formal.